# Annoying generator bug

Tags: python, generator

*The original context of this bug is a piece of code too large to post in a question like this.  I had to whittle this code down to a minimal snippet that still exhibits the bug.  This is why the code shown below is somewhat bizarre-looking.*

In the code below, the class `Foo` may thought of as a convoluted way to get something like `xrange`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.generator = (x for x in range(n))

    def __iter__(self):
        for e in self.generator:
            yield e
```

Indeed, `Foo` seems to behave very much like `xrange`:

```
for c in Foo(3):
    print c
# 0
# 1
# 2

print list(Foo(3))
# [0, 1, 2]
```

Now, the subclass `Bar` of `Foo` adds only a `__len__` method:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def __len__(self):
        return sum(1 for _ in self.generator)
```

`Bar` behaves just like `Foo` when used in a `for`-loop:

```
for c in Bar(3):
    print c
# 0
# 1
# 2
```

BUT:

```
print list(Bar(3))
# []
```

My guess is that, in the evaluation of `list(Bar(3))`, the `__len__` method of `Bar(3)` is getting called, thereby using up the generator.

(If this guess is correct, the call to `Bar(3).__len__` is unnecessary; after all, `list(Foo(3))` produces the correct result even though `Foo` has no `__len__` method.)

This situation is annoying: there's no good reason for `list(Foo(3))` and `list(Bar(3))` to produce different results.

Is it possible to fix `Bar` (without, of course, getting rid of its `__len__` method) such that `list(Bar(3))` returns `[0, 1, 2]`?

Comment: What if the generator is infinite?

Comment: @thefourtheye: since, AFAICT, the scenario you propose cannot happen in the code presented, I don't know how to interpret your question.

Comment: You're right that `list(Bar(3))` calls `__len__` (which you can see as simply as adding a print statement to your len method). My question is: you know generators can be exhausted and should only be used once, so instead of storing the generator object itself, why not design your class to _know how to generate one_ on demand?

Comment: A generator doesn't have a length.  I think that what thefourtheye is getting as is that, since a generator could be infinite, it's hopeless to try to define a length method for a generator.  Your guess as to what is wrong with list(Bar(3)) is correct.  I don't think there is any way to do what you want without making a copy of the generator, which seems a bit extreme, but may be worthwhile in your app.  (I haven't thought about how to make a copy of generator, though.  I'm not sure it's possible.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that Foo does not behave the same as xrange: xrange gives you a new iterator each time you asks its `iter` method, while Foo gives you always the same, meaning that once it is exhausted the object is too:

```
>>> a = Foo(3)
>>> list(a)
[0, 1, 2]
>>> list(a)
[]
>>> a = range(3)
>>> list(a)
[0, 1, 2]
>>> list(a)
[0, 1, 2]
```

I could easily confirm that the `__len__` method is called by `list` by adding spys to your methods:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def __len__(self):
        print "LEN"
        return sum(1 for _ in self.generator)
```

(and I added a `print "ITERATOR"` in `Foo.__iter__`). It yields:

```
>>> list(Bar(3))
LEN
ITERATOR
[]
```

I can only imagine two workarounds:

1. my preferred one: return a new iterator on each call to `__iter__` at `Foo` level to mimic `xrange`:

   ```
   class Foo(object):
       def __init__(self, n):
           self.n = n

       def __iter__(self):
           print "ITERATOR"
           return ( x for x in range(self.n))

   class Bar(Foo):
       def __len__(self):
           print "LEN"
           return sum(1 for _ in self.generator)
   ```

   we get correctly:

   ```
   >>> list(Bar(3))
   ITERATOR
   LEN
   ITERATOR
   [0, 1, 2]
   ```
2. the alternative: change len to not call the iterator and let `Foo` untouched:

   ```
   class Bar(Foo):
       def __init__(self, n):
           self.len  = n
           super(Bar, self).__init__(n)
       def __len__(self):
           print "LEN"
           return self.len
   ```

   Here again we get:

   ```
   >>> list(Bar(3))
   LEN
   ITERATOR
   [0, 1, 2]
   ```

   but Foo and Bar objects are exhausted once first iterator reaches its end.

But I must admit that I do not know the context of your real classes...

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour might be annoying but it's actually quite understandable. Internally a `list` is simply an array and an array is a fixed size datastructure. The result of this is that if you have a `list` that has size `n` and you want to add an extra item to reach `n+1` it will have to create a whole new array and completely copy the old one to the new one. Effectively your `list.append(x)` is now a `O(n)` operation instead of the regular `O(1)`.

To prevent this, `list()` tries to get the size of your input so it can guess what size the array needs to be.

So one solution for this problem is to force it to guess by using `iter`:

```
list(iter(Bar(3)))
```